# Como reutilizar um layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Quero criar uma tela com menu de redações, como faço para "reutilizar" um layout para ter várias redações e menos arquivos layout (xml).

Comment: Usando um [Adapter com um arquivo XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35240906/using-an-external-xml-file-for-custom-list-view-adapter)?

Comment: Não entendi direito, teria que criar um custom adapter com uma lista ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi da sua pergunta é isso, mas posso ter entendido mal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ter um `Fragment` ou  uma `Activity` com um `layout` fixo, recebendo parâmetros diferentes para que você possa inflar os campos da maneira que você quiser dependendo dos parâmetros recebidos. Fazendo isso você pode esconder campos que você não usa em um caso X mas usa no caso Y, usando a função `.setVisibility`

Ex:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_padrao);

        Textview txtNotaUm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNotaUm);
        Textview txtNotaDois = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNotaDois);

        Boolean tipoUm = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("tipoUm");

        if(tipoUm){               
           txtNotaUm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           txtNotaDois.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
           txtNotaUm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           txtNotaDois.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }    
    }
```